# TFS Requirement-based suite displayed in MTM as a Test Suite or Web Access Test Suite --are they configurable SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint, testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

In MTM the Test Suite lists I have are requirements based.  They display the work item id, the title and the priority.  I would like to change the display to be based on other fields, most importantly 'Requirement Number'.  I suspect the lists are configurable based on the list attributes in SharePoint.  Can anyone confirm that for me?  I do not have access to the servers here, but I suspect manipulation to the SP list object might trickle down into the way the list is displayed in the MTM and Web Access Views.

(the next day)
I have done a bit more reading and my path forward might involve editing the Work Item Template in TFS to capture additional fields and with TFS "Process Editor" to impact the UI on MTM etc.  I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 5):

Web Access nor MTM use Sharepoint to configure anything. Sharepoint is only an optional component in the TFS deployment and has no influence on any of the internal configurations of the TFS process template or how things are displayed.

The name of the Requirement Based Suite is generated when the suite is created, but after that it's just a string. If you want it to be something else, you can simply rename the Suite to be anything you want.

As far as I know there is no way to influence the default naming scheme for Requirement based Suites.